# Add custom validation to custom user profile field

Tags: php, moodle

I am using Moodle 3.1+. I am trying to add a custom validation into profile edit. The field is a custom user profile field. I have created a function

```
function validYop($element_name,$element_value) {
    $len = strlen($element_value);

    // If the string is empty, then return false

    if ($len == 0) { return false; }

    $first_letter = $element_value{0};

    $last_letter = $element_value{$len-1};

    if ($first_letter == $last_letter) {

    return true;

    } else {

    return false;

    }
    }
```

Then I have registered the rule using below code.

```
$mform->registerRule('same_firstandlast','function','validYop'); 
        $mform->addRule('profile_field_YearOfPassing','The first and last letters must be the same', 'same_firstandlast');
```

But the code is not working. Please help

Comment: What do you mean with "the code is not working"?

Comment: Validation is not working

Comment: Just a thought: in the registerRule() method,  you could try to use the same string for both the rule name and the function name, like $mform->registerRule('validYop','function','validYop'); and see if it works.

Comment: Of course, here the addRule() parameters should be changed accordingly: $mform->addRule('profile_field_YearOfPassing','The first and last letters must be the same', 'validYop');